# Javafx app GUI freezes while executing a query

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

I'm trying to build an application that will execute several queries in a loop. Queries are to be executed one by one (one after the other). If I do code in one thread, the GUI freezes for the duration of the queries (they take a while) and only after they are finished is it active again, and I would like to have a working progress bar as well.

```
protected void onButtonClick() throws InterruptedException {
    String[] array = getIDs();

    progressText.setText("Starting...");
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        progressText.setText("Updated: " + i + " of " + array.length + " ids.");

        executeSingleQuery(array[i]);
    }
    progressText.setText("Done!");
}
```

I know I should work on threads probably, but I don't really know how. If I add

```
new Thread(() ->executeSingleQuery(array[i])).start();
```

to the loop, a new thread will be created with each iteration, and my point is that the queries should be executed one at a time; plus I want the progress bar to work properly.
Can you help me find a solution?

Comment: Use a `javafx.concurrent.Task` (and use its API for messages/progress). See [Concurrency in JavaFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm#JFXIP546).

Comment: Alternatively you can execute the entire for loop on a separate thread.  When you update the GUI do it using the JavaFx thread by `Platform.runLater(()->  progressText.setText("Starting..."));`